# Excel running total on Financial year (Apr to March) and reset on the next financial year

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm trying use excel power query to calculate the running total of the cost based on Financial year. I've used index and list.sum function to achieve the running total but when it reach next financial year it will still accumulate last year cost. Kindly see table below (Yellow is 1st financial and orange is 2nd financial year)

[image]

This is what i trying to achieve, the running total will reset at April 2022. May i know is there any query code to achieve this kind of results? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in powerquery to group on year, and add a running total for that year based off of the **Total** column

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Month", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Total", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Year"}, {{"data", each 
    let a=Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    b= Table.AddColumn(a, "Running Total", each List.Sum(List.FirstN(a[Total],[Index2])))
    in b
, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Month", "Total", "Running Total"}, {"Month", "Total", "Running Total"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]